# Concurrent Read/Write in MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, concurrency, jvm, locking

I have a collection from which I am getting max id and while inserting using max id + 1. The id column is unique in this collection.

When multiple instances of this service is invoked the concurrent application reads the same collection and gets the max id. But since the same collection is accessed the same max id is returned to multiple instances, can I get an explicit lock on the collection while reading the data from this collection and release the lock after writing in Mongo DB?

Comment: Have you tried using external synchronization or inbuilt synchronized collections?

Comment: Could you please elaborate, do we have synchronized collections in MongoDB ?

Comment: Could you write a bit more what you want to achieve? Looks like you need transactions so maybe MongoDB is not the best option here. Consider    [auto incrementing sequence field](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/#auto-increment-counters-collection) or [$inc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) if you just need atomic way to increment some counter.

Comment: The application is written where the back end is Mongo DB. I have exposed a service where we want to do auto increment in the MongoDB collection. Since multiple instances of this service is exposed, multiple services are trying to access and update Db at same time which is causing the incosistency in DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using mongoDB method `collections.findAndModify()` you can create your own "get-and-increment" query.

For example:

```
db.collection_name.findAndModify({
  query: { document_identifier: "doc_id_1" },
  update: { $inc: { max_id: 1 } },
  new: true  //return the document AFTER it's updated
})
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/

Take a look at this page for more help:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_autoincrement_sequence.htm

Comment: that is great! You got my. +1.

Comment: so does this before executing, add a lock on the document?

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach

Instead of getting the `max id` in read of the collection and increment it as `max id + 1`.

While read for multiple instances just give the document/collection, and while updating follow the below logic

```
Let us have the below part in a synchronized block, so that no two threads gets the same max id
synchronize() {
  getMaxId from collection
  increase it by 1
  insert the new document
}
```

Please refer:

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_autoincrement_sequence.htm

Hope it Helps!